# What is atltime.h in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, atl

Can someone will explain to me What is atltime.h ? I don't know how this header works. I tried to search it on google but i didn't get an answer of what atltime. h is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not MFC, but ATL.  ATL (Active Template Library) is a set of header files that ships with Visual Studio for making Windows programming easier without having to pull in all of MFC. These headers implement C++ class libraries that do useful things for legacy Windows programming.

It appear that `atltime.h` has the declarations for the following classes:

[`CTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/ctime-class?view=msvc-170), [`CTimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/ctimespan-class?view=msvc-170), [`CFileTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cfiletime-class?view=msvc-170), etc...